# Retrieving image file in reactjs

Tags: api, reactjs, express, multer

I am retrieving an image file from my api via my react front end. I am unsure how I can display the image once it is returned as my component receive a response with a blob promise that has not resolved when the component mounts.

Here is my backend api using express.js, specifically the part responding with the file that was earlier saved using multer.

```
Pet.findOne({_id : req.params.petId}, function(err, pet) {
          if(err)return next(err);
          if(!pet){
            return res.status(400).json({message:"Pet not found", success: false});
          }
          res.sendFile(pet.profilePicturePath, {root : './'});
        });
```

This finds the pets image from the mongodb and then uses express' sendFile method to respond to my front end request here:

```
fetch('/api'+nextState.location.pathname,{
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: tokenFound
      })
    })
    .then((res)=>{
      if(res.error){
        browserHistory.push('/login')
      }
      return res;
    }).then((json) =>{
      if(json.success === false){
        browserHistory.push('/login');
      }else{
        localStorage.setItem('token', tokenFound);
        nextState.routes.json = json;
      }
    }).then((blob) => {
      nextState.routes.blob = blob;
      cb();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error token: ' + err));
  }else{
    browserHistory.push('/login');
    cb();
  }
```

When I go to my component, PetPage, that calls the above function onEnter '' I am not sure how to display the image file that I receive.

Comment: use this line: <img src={require('./avatar.jpg'})/>

Comment: Could you provide more update on what is ` cb();` and whether you are using any library like `redux` to manage async data api?

Comment: @SourLeangChhean using <img src={require('./avatar.jpg'})/> will not work because I need to make an api call to retrieve the image file and while doing so provide a jwt to check the user is authorized.

Comment: @NagarajTantri yeah, cb() is the call back function that allows me to run this fetch method within my react routes.js file and then render my component. I am using it to check if a user is logged in, and then if confirmed by the api direct them appropriately. I am not using redux to async load, I am not sure how redux works but I am receiving a promise from my backend that eventually resolves.

Comment: @Athomas1 Then can you show us the invocation of this api, via your reactJs component?